# Is there An Appllication For Testing Various File I/O In Windows?

Tags: windows, file-io, filesystems, ntfs, smb

I'm developing a network-redirector like SMB.
I want to test various file I/O to compare NTFS or SMB implementation.

What I want to test are,

- CreateFile
- Read, WriteFile
- DeleteFile
- RenameFile
- Set, GetFileInformationByHandle
- etc.

And it' would be better if it can measure each I/Os duration.

Is there a program I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing a file system driver or use some redirector driver (either our Callback File System or alternatives), you can use [IFSTest tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563405%28VS.85%29.aspx) to check your implementation for correctness.

Comment: I think it is the closest one I'm looking for. I'll try it. Thanks Eugene.

Answer (score 1):

XPerf will answer all of these questions, allowing you to see perf at both the file level and the block level. Check out the PDC09 video on the topic at http://www.microsoftpdc.com/2009/CL16

Answer (score 1):

You can use the File Server Capacity Tool (FSCT) provided by Microsoft. It will let you simulate a typical user workload against a file server that supports SMB. The tool can simulate multiple users from a single client and aggregates the results into text files in the end.

You can get more information, including links to download and detailed presentations at http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2009/09/16/file-server-capacity-tool-fsct-1-0-available-for-download.aspx